# does moss on maple tree harm it?

Tags: plant-health

We have a red maple that after growing for 35 yrs has suddenly developed moss on the trunk. It is very dark in color, almost black. Is this a threat to our trees health?

Comment: Can you add a photo please?

Comment: Moss does not harm trees as mentioned in this answer here https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/31002/499 but we would still like to see a picture to make sure it is moss and not decay fungi

Comment: A photo will help. I think it is a lichen or a fungi, not a moss. Moss is easy to remove. Try to remove and check if there are other problems. Mosses do no cause (directly) problems (usually), but they can provide shelter to insect, or humidity for fungi.